# How do I go about structuring/coding my site to have easily published articles?

Tags: archive, publishing, article

I'm really only a novice in HTML and CSS, with very little knowledge in JS or other coding.  What I'm trying to accomplish is having my site set up in a way where the webmaster (me) can publish multiple "articles" on a daily basis and have them a.) appear on the home page and b.) be placed in an archive for easy access by readers.

As an example, I referring to a structure like this: http://www.cinemablend.com/games/

Currently I'm going the archaic route of manually editing my index.html (either through Notepad or Dreamweaver), placing the "articles" in cells, 10 articles per page.  When I reach that limit and add a new article, I will have to painstakingly move each article down a cell, and place the bottom article in a manually created "archive" page.  Needless to say, this would get tedious, but I know of no other way around this, nor how to word my query to find the solution online.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly unless you are decently skilled in PHP, Ruby, Python, or other server-side languages, it is extremely difficult (and not to mention impractical) to get a full CMS (content management system) in purely client-side code, with HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

Unless you want to learn Ruby, etc. (which is something I recommend in general, but a web server is probably not a good first project), you are best off using a pre-built CMS system like **[Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/)** (or Blogger).  Wordpress is nice in that you can apply whatever HTML, CSS, and Javascript you want to make it look like whatever you want; it handles all of the posting and "manual" stuff (making separate article pages, keeping a front page updated, allowing comments, easy way to add articles) that you mentioned, yet you can still build the HTML/CSS by yourself from scratch if you want.

However Wordpress is a thriving community with many community-made themes/HTML/CSS you can use already, and most people chose this option instead of building their own from scratch.